# How to get column-level protection of the original tables in security_invoker views?

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple table "users", for which I want to block access to the password for some role "alice".

```sql
-- create table and some example data
create table users (
  username text,
  password text
);

insert into users(username, password) values
    ('foo', 'foopass'),
    ('bar', 'barpass');

-- create a role and limit its access
create role "alice";
grant select("username") on users to "alice";
```

So far so good. Using the "alice" role will successfully run `select "username" from users` but not `select "password" from users`.

However, problems arise when I introduce a view:

```sql
-- create a simple view
create view users_view with (security_invoker) as (
  select * from users
);
grant select on "users_view" to public;
```

Now if I run (as "alice") `select "username" from users_view`, it fails because *"permission denied for table users"*.

[Full db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u6mtBe1M5eVj6ei6Sv5qXv/0)

This is not what I expect from `security_invoker`. Is there a way this could still work, without completely overhauling the definition of the view?

Comment: 1) You only granted select on column `username` to `alice`, yet the view is `select * from users`. 2) You did not say what role you ran `select "username" from users_view` as? 3) In `psql` what does `\dp users_view` return? **Add answers as text update to question**.

Comment: Why do you give direct access to the table when also give access the same data by using the view? Personally I would use just one access path, instead of two or more.

Comment: Why is that *"not what I expect from `security_invoker`"*? 1. You restricted Alice's access to just one column `username` in table `user`. 2. You defined a view that uses her access. 3. *"the user of a security invoker view must have the relevant permissions on the view and its underlying base relations."* - when Alice tries to use the view, she ends up trying to `select *` so that fails. The only scenario where this could work is if the query rewrite system merged the view definition into the statement and reduced the query to `select username` *before* verifying privileges on its final form.

Comment: @Zegarek that's indeed what I expected

Comment: @FrankHeikens The view I'm actually using in my app has more things going on with it, this is just a minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way this could still work, without completely overhauling the definition of the view?

That's kind of asking if this could work without changing things that make this not work. No.

> This is not what I expect from `security_invoker`.

1. You restricted Alice's access to just one column `username` in table `user`.
2. You defined a view that relies on her access privileges.
3. You told Alice to `select username from (select * from users)` where `*` includes `password` column she doesn't have sufficient access privileges for. [Unsurprisingly](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html#id-1.9.3.97.7):

   > the user of a security invoker view must have the relevant permissions on the view and its underlying base relations

   and she doesn't, so that fails.

The only scenario where this *could be expected* to work is if the [query rewrite system](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-privileges.html) merged the view definition into the statement and reduced the query to `select username` first, then only verified privileges on its final form, after that. Here's another illustration: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Hwqb2tEj)

```sql
create role "Eve";
create table "tree_of_knowledge"(forbidden_fruit money default 666);
revoke all privileges on "tree_of_knowledge" from "Eve";
create view sinful_view with (security_invoker) as (
with original_sin as (
  select--no columns            --"I'm not touching anything"
  from "tree_of_knowledge"
  where false--nothing qualifies--"I'm really touching nothing"
  limit 0)--zero of those       --"Even if I was, I'm not"
  select 'Forgive me father for I have sinned.' repent --constant, unrelated to anything
  from original_sin --"I'm touching nothing, nowhere and there's nothing in there."
  limit 0           --"Not even, at all."
);
grant select on sinful_view to public;
set role "Eve";
select repent from sinful_view limit 0;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  permission denied for table tree_of_knowledge
> ```

```
select/*nothing*/ from sinful_view limit 0;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  permission denied for table tree_of_knowledge
> ```

The way PostgreSQL works, Eve isn't allowed to even smell the forbidden tree,  no matter how much she promises to behave. We're not taking any more risks.

Comment: That makes it very clear, no query rewrite magic is ever going to happen. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only ways to avoid the problem are

1. define the view with the default `security_invoker = off`
2. create a view that only selects the "allowed" columns